# Replaceing a cell with the value of the cell below it using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column of period types either Y, Q, or M.
I need to replace all of the Ys with the period type of the column below. 
I have used a for loop but the run time is way too long. Any suggestions on how to do this without a for loop.

This is the code I have now:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    data.1$PeriodType <- replace(data.1$PeriodType, data.1[i,11]=="Y", data.1[i+1,11])
}
```

(my actual data frame has 202696 columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data.1 %>% 
  mutate(PeriodType = if_else(PeriodType == "Y", 
                              lag(PeriodType, n = 1L),
                              PeriodType))
```

Although I think a safer way to do this (assuming you don't have any prior `NA's`) would be to replace all your `PeriodType == "Y"` with `NA` first, and then using `tidyr` to `fill` the data (by replacing the NAs`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.1 %>% 
  mutate(PeriodType = if_else(PeriodType == "Y",
                              NA_character_,
                              PeriodType)) %>% 
  fill(PeriodType, direction = "up")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Where you lag the values up and then you can just do a simple ifelse statement.

```
shift <- function(x, lag) {
      n <- length(x)
      xnew <- rep(NA, n)
      if (lag < 0) {
        xnew[1:(n-abs(lag))] <- x[(abs(lag)+1):n]
      } else if (lag > 0) {
        xnew[(lag+1):n] <- x[1:(n-lag)]
      } else {
        xnew <- x
      }
      return(xnew)
    }

    data.1$PeriodType_Shift <- shift(data.1$PeriodType, -1)
    ifelse(data.1PeriodType == "Y", data.1PeriodType_Shift, data.1$PeriodType)
```